# SQL Server database or database on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm writing windows application which will be used on one computer. I like to do with SQL server, retrieve data with stored procedures, and so...
My question is, what is the difference between SQL server database (in file) and standard db on SQL server, because I don't want to install SQL server on client's PC just for one app. Can be this SQL server DB used with stored procedures, or is there other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to install a full SQL Server engine on the client machine you could use an embedded database such as [SQL Server Compact](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx) or [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) which are designed for those scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx), [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) or something like [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/). I don't think any of these really offers a way to run a database engine without installing *something* or requiring something else to be installed (e.g. you could use `AttachDbFileName` method with SQL Server but this relies on VS/Express to already be there).

Comment: Unless you understand that deploying a few files and making no changes on windows registry, windows system file and so on is installing, you are completely wrong. SQL CE and SQLite are distributed simply by copying files. That's not an installation!

Comment: @JotaBe if you read the question, the OP seemed to want to just give the user a file and expect it to be able to run. My point was that something else has to take place in order to use the database file. You can argue about what constitutes an installation all you want.